# Error during TFS Extension installation yields in invisible Extension

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have developed a custom TFS Extension and tried to install it on my on-premise TFS 2017. During upload in the extension gallery (http://tfs:8080/tfs/_gallery/manage) an error occured telling me about malformed content of my vsix package. After fixing the issue, i could not install the extension, because TFS says "The extension already exists.". Problem is, it does not show up in the gallery. So i have no chance to uninstall or update it. Instead i had to pick a new ID in vss-extension.json.

Seems like during the faulty installation, some database entries or files were left on the server. Anybody an idea were to look for those or any alternate ways to delete the extension?

The `Gallery.tbl_Extension` table contains an entry with ID of the faulty extension. So this is not an issue with cached data on the server or client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if the extension does not show up in the extension gallery, you can query the TFS REST API and see if the extension (or remaining parts of it) is installed:
http://tfs:8080/tfs/_apis/gallery/publishers/MyPublisher/extensions/MyExtensionID

Next you need to install and remove an arbitrary extension from the TFS Marketplace and record the REST calls (using Chrome Dev Tools or  Postman Interceptor for example).

You will find a DELETE request, that includes all necessary header information. You just need to update the publisher and extension id in the url to match the package you want to remove and send it to the TFS. On success the server will return 204 Not Content.

This seems to be an undocumented TFS API, since i could not find any infos about it in the current API documentation (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview).

Answer (score 0):

The extension's ID just  means an identifier. Which is a string that must be **unique** among extensions from the same publisher.

Since the extension is upload and not installed properly. And looking through the list of extensions, it's also not appear in the list. This maybe a cache issue.

Try to clean the client caches (both TFS and Browser)

- TFS:    `C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\{version}\Cache`
- Browser, IE for example (based on your settings) :

  `C:\Users\{your account}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache`